# Long deployment time

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We experienced a few issues this morning where we queued a release and took 54 minutes to deploy. This process normally takes around 10 minutes to complete.

The release in question began the "Pre-deployment approval" phase at 09:26 and the "Agent phase" only started at 10:12. What could the possible reasons be for the time between these two phases?

The hosted agent seemed to be pretty idle between those times - in that no other builds or releases were in progress. We are currently only utilising a single, purchased hosted pipeline, but if it appeared to be idle then this shouldn't be an issue - should it?

**Logs**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the start time for Pre-deployment approval (start at 09:26) and Agent phase (start at 10:12), the **Pre-deployment approval takes 46 minutes**. So the tasks for deployment take 8 minutes (54-46), and the time for deployment seems work normally.

And for the Pre-deployment approval, it’s mainly manually now (specify certain users, not automatically). If it’s ok for you to set Pre-deployment approval automatic, you can change it in your release definition.

[image]

To double check Pre-deployment approval is approved by someone or automatically, please click the approval icon.
If it’s approved automatically, it should be:

[image]

If it’s approved by someone, it should be:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The *Pre-deployment approval* phase has always been set to run automatically and usually completes fairly quickly. It is just the odd occasion, such as the one described above, where it took much longer.

Comment: So what's the pre-deployment approval logs for this release?

Comment: Edited original question to include screenshots of the logs.

Comment: Please also click the approval icon for Pre-deployment approval, to double check it's approved automatically or by someone?

Comment: And I added the screen shots for approved automatically and by someone separately in the end of my answer.

Comment: I've clicked the approval icon and it indeed matches the first screenshot above - indicating it has been approved automatically.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue for now?

Comment: It hasn't happened on subsequent deployments as yet no. It may be possible that it was an issue at that particular period and is no longer an issue.